# AS3 Facebook app - app reloads in Facebook login window upon login on IE8-9

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook app written in AS3, using the Adobe Facebook Api.

It works perfectly on all browsers but IE8 and 9.  If the user is not already logged into Facebook, the app will ask them to log in, and accept permissions if they haven't already.  That's where it all goes wrong.  Upon logging in, the app reloads and reinitializes **INSIDE** the login popup.  The expected behavior, the behavior seen in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, is that the login window should close, and the app should receive the login success callback. This callback is never received by the app that is in the page tab.

Hopefully someone has a thought on how to solve this.  I have searched hi and low.  I tried p3p headers, all kinds of channel url stuff, and a whole heap of various possible fixes I read about online.  Nothing is changing the behavior.

my facebook init is as follows( I tried both):

```
Facebook.init(APP_ID, onInitFacebook);
Facebook.init(APP_ID, onInitFacebook, {channelUrl:'http://www.somesite.com/channel.html'});
```

and for login:

```
Facebook.login(handleLogin, {scope:'publish_stream, user_photos'});
```

Anyone have an idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

```
params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
params.allownetworking = "all";
params.wmode = "transparent";
```

don't ask me why, but set params in swfobject.embedSWF works for me... :)

good luck!

Comment: This suggestion does not address the issue.  The post states that the application reloads inside the login dialog box rather than informing the page the application is currently in that the login was successful.  allowscriptaccess was already set to "always" anyway.